# Python search .txt file for specific line

Tags: python, regex

Basically I want a Python script to search a `.txt` for any line containing,

```
" #1111. "
```

`1111` < = any number from `0-9`, so any possibility `0-9` with `4` numbers, containing `#` at the start and `.` at the end.

Comment: `matches = [line for line in lines if re.search("#\\d{4}.", line) is not None]`

Comment: If you want a proper answer, have a crack at it and then share your code if you cannot get it to work properly.

Comment: @zondo, your regex has mistake. you have escaped back slash twice. it should be `#\d{4}.`

Comment: @Saleem: You're right.  I corrected that in my tests, but forgot to change my comment.

Comment: @Saleem: Well, @zondo didn't use raw strings (which you should _always_ do with Python regexes), so the double escape is in fact correct. The lack of an escape for the `.` is an error though. Using raw strings (like you should _always_ do with Python regexes), the correct pattern would be `r'#\d{4}\.'`, or if the leading and trailing spaces are expected, `r' #\d{4}\. '`.

Comment: hmmm, please see this link where `\d` is escaped once. https://regex101.com/r/pJ7yL9/1 you'll see it's matching correctly. but if you follow https://regex101.com/r/pJ7yL9/2 where i have double escaped, you'll notice nothing is matching.

Comment: however, un-escaped period is my typo mistake.

Comment: @Saleem: The regex101 site is implicitly using something equivalent to Python's raw strings. That's why the double backslash is wrong there; with a raw string, you only want one backslash. As it happens, in Python, for the letter `d` in a non-raw string `\\d` and `\d` are the same, because Python is stupid, and treats backslashes preceding letters that cannot be interpreted as escape codes as if it is a backslash followed by original letter, not just the original letter. So `\\d` and `\d` are the same in non-raw strings, but `\a` and `\b` are the ASCII bell and backspace characters. It's dumb.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use what's called a [Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Python has a regular expression module called [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

```
import re

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    matches = [line for line in f if re.search(r'#\d{4}\.', line)]
print matches
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `#`

Comment: Also, _always_ use raw strings for regexes (I cannot say this too many times), and don't bother calling `.readlines()` (which just forces a slurp of all the lines before filtering, increasing peak memory usage dramatically, when just doing `for line in f` pulls lines lazily on demand, improving the ability of the OS to precache, and reducing peak memory usage to match the number of matches, not the total number of lines. Lastly, opening the file in binary mode seems a little odd; we're processing text here, so read it as such.

Comment: @ShadowRanger good point.

Comment: Answer changed to reflect suggestions.